# Postgres to Hdfs data import using Sqoop job is giving Unrecognized argument: --schema error

Tags: postgresql, sqoop

i am working on sqoop incremental import from postgres to HDFS directory.Sqoop is working properly and i am able to get incremental data by using the following sqoop command,

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.130:5432/sqoop_test --username postgres --password track@123 --table sample_test -m 1 --warehouse-dir /user/hdfs --incremental lastmodified --check-column start_time --merge-key id -- --schema analyst
```

now i am trying to create a sqoop job for the same import command as follows,

```
sqoop job --create incident_import -- import --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.130:5432/sqoop_test --username postgres --password track@123 --table sample_test -m 1 --warehouse-dir /user/hdfs --incremental lastmodified --check-column start_time --merge-key id -- --schema analyst
```

but when i am executing sqoop job as,

```
sqoop job --exec incident_import
```

it is giving the following error as,

```
 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --schema
 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: analyst
```

I am not able to find the cause.anybody have any idea please suggest me.

Comment: try `--schema analyst` instead of `-- --schema analyst` in **sqoop job** command.

Comment: thank you dev. I  tried this then it's giving ERROR [main] manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sample_test" does not exist
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sample_test" does not exist
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1548)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1316)
Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter  .